# Query on mongodb on max date of embedded list

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have json like below I want to build query so that I will pass one date and I want if hoardings contains statusQueues then max campaignEndDate is less than the entered date should be returned. How can I do that?

```
"hoardings" : [ {     
      "isActive" : false,
      "id" : "5a9a4c7af5369628809e8124",      
      "statusQueues" : [ {
        "campaignStartDate" : "03 Mar, 2018",
        "campaignEndDate" : "27 Mar, 2018",
        "module" : "Campaign"
      }, {
        "campaignStartDate" : "03 Mar, 2018",
        "campaignEndDate" : "28 Mar, 2018",
        "module" : "Campaign"
      }, {
        "campaignStartDate" : "03 Mar, 2018",
        "campaignEndDate" : "29 Mar, 2018",
        "module" : "Campaign"
      },
{
        "campaignStartDate" : "03 Mar, 2018",
        "campaignEndDate" : "20 Mar, 2018",
        "module" : "Campaign"
      } ]      
    },
 {     
      "isActive" : false,
      "id" : "5a9a4c7af5369628809e8125",      
      "statusQueues" : [  ]      
    }]
```

I have tried using mongoTemplate but unable to write query for that.

Comment: what  is your project setup, how are you querying mongodb from your application? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Update the question with what have you tried so far.

Comment: In my project I am doing queries using mongoTemplate in spring boot but for this situation I am unable to build query. @pvpkiran

Comment: what do you meant by "max campaignEndDate is less than the entered date"

Comment: Actually result will be displayed directly to the UI. So I am exposing a rest API to search where user will send a date and he will expect all the hoarding which max campaignEndDate is less than the user input date.